# setTimeout and clearTimeout on alternate clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a front-end to a task management system, and I'm stuck on a setTimeout problem. I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks the checkbox, the tile fades to 33% opacity/toggle a "completed" class, waits 2 seconds, and then disappears; if the user clicks again on the checkbox before it disappears, the task should toggle the class and clear the timeout.

I am having a lot of trouble getting the clearTimeout command to work. I have declared my timer variable outside of the relevant blocks, tried adding the clearQueue() and stop() commands to my function, and triple-checked spelling.

My JS fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sLYA9/.

Here is my relevant JS:

```
$('#alltasks .taskitem form').click( function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Variables for different referenced elements
  var tile = $( this ).parent('.taskitem');
  var taskContents = '<div class=\'taskitem\' draggable=\'true\'>' + tile.html() + '</div>';
  var timer;

  // Unchecking a checked task
  if (tile.hasClass('completed')) {
    clearTimeout( timer );
    tile.clearQueue().stop().fadeTo( 300, 1 );
  } else { // Checking an unchecked task
    tile.fadeTo( 300, 0.33 );
    timer = setTimeout( function() {
      alert("the task disappears");
    }, 2000 );
  }
  tile.toggleClass('completed');

});
```

Again, I would like the user to be able to click the checkbox again before the 2000 ms timer is up and clear the timer.

Any ideas what I missed?

---

EDIT: I feel silly now. Moving my timer declaration outside of the click handler function made it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer scoped in the first "click" function.  If you move var timer outside of the click callback it works.  You could just check when the timer fires to see if it is still "complete"

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the timer is local so each time it is called you have a new scope.

The variable timer needs to be declared outside of the click function.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Thanks! (I just moved my var timer; out of my click handler function)